# Why is the default android camera preview smoother than my own camera preview?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I just setup a very basic camera preview that displays the camera full screen. I compared the smoothness of both my app and the android camera and figured that the android camera seems a lot smoother.

Why is that the case? Are there any special tricks to improve the camera preview performance?

Comment: Maybe you can set your camera fps higher.

Comment: Is it possible that the android camera app uses some kind of async task functionality? Has anyone ever tried to build a custom camera app that uses an async task?

Comment: Dear god, yes. I've been trying to figure this out myself. Diving into the camera source, I'm not seeing anything significantly different, and they use the maximum available preview size as well. I've tried with callback buffers for the preview display, using a TextureView instead of SurfaceView, just about everything I can think of with no luck. I'd love to hear if you find a solution for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I faced the same issue a time ago, and it turned out to be related with the camera resolution. Chances are that your `Camera` is initializing with the maximum available resolution, which may slow down performance during preview. Try and set a lower `picture size` with something like this.-

```
Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
params.setPictureSize(1280, 960);
camera.setParameters(params);
```

Notice that you'll need to set an available picture size. You can check available sizes with

```
camera.getParameters().getSupportedPictureSizes();
```

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**

It seems using a picture size with different aspect ratio than the default one, slows down performance as well. This is how I choose my `pictureSize`.-

First off, I get the aspect ratio of the camera default `pictureSize`

```
Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
defaultCameraRatio = (float) params.getPictureSize().width / (float) params.getPictureSize().height;
```

And then I get a lower `pictureSize` that fits the same ratio.-

```
private Size getPreferredPictureSize() {
    Size res = null;
    List<Size> sizes = camera.getParameters().getSupportedPictureSizes();

    for (Size s : sizes) {
        float ratio = (float) s.width / (float) s.height;
        if (ratio == defaultCameraRatio && s.height <= PHOTO_HEIGHT_THRESHOLD) {
            res = s;
    break;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Where `PHOTO_HEIGHT_THRESHOLD` is the max height you want to allow.

Comment: The stock Camera app uses a preview size that matches the viewfinder (i.e. that should be the largest available preview size); you can see this in com.android.camera.Util#getOptimalPreviewSize(). Reducing the preview size certainly helps with performance, but the stock app is able to get away with full resolution much more smoothly.

Comment: Mmh and which method does it use that `optimalPreviewSize` with? `setPictureSize` or `setPreviewSize`? In my app, setting a lower preview size with `setPreviewSize` didn't make much difference.

Comment: Oh interesting. Are you saying lowering the *picture* size rather than the *preview* size improved your performance? Even if you are not taking pictures? The code I was referring to is definitely only relating to the preview size.

Comment: That's right, I tried everything, including changing `previewSize` and using callback buffers. However with `setPictureSize` I got by far the best results (at least I can't find the difference with the android camera app). Actually, I'm currently not touching `previewSize` at all.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to make any difference for me. I set my picture size to 176 x 144, but it looks the same.

Comment: Mmh maybe I did something else I'm missing, let me check again.

Comment: Ok, just tried 176 x 144 and slows down too. I guess it has to do with the aspect ratio as well. Please, try and get default cameraRatio (`defaultCameraRatio = (float) params.getPictureSize().width / (float) params.getPictureSize().height;`) and set a picture size with the same ratio.

Comment: If this works it has to be a bug in the APIs. I'll give it a shot here shortly. :)

Comment: Have an upvote. :) Strangely, using one of the same aspect ratio *did* improve performance, but it also affected the quality of the preview image, which implies that somehow it's also changing the preview size internally to match? Either way, it's better, but still nowhere close to the performance of the stock camera viewfinder. :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37631/discussion-between-ssantos-and-kcoppock)

Answer (score 2):

This answer is a bit late, but after struggling with the same problem, I figured I'd share what I found.

Not only was I unable to match the stock camera's "smoothness", but I was also unable to match the metering of the stock camera.  My live preview was much darker compared to the stock camera, especially in low light situations.

My solution was ultimately an FPS issue, as originally proposed by Robin in an early comment.

The default preview FPS on the Nexus 5 is a static 15 FPS.  The stock android app detects and sets a preview FPS that uses a dynamic range (as long as that range includes 30fps).  On a nexus 5, that range is 7fps -> 30fps.  In low light the camera drops to a lower FPS to keep the preview bright, while in bright conditions it jumps to a smooth 30 fps.

**Relevant code from the stock android photo app:**

- The call to set the FPS starts on line 1560 of com.android.camera.PhotoModule (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera2/+/android-4.4.4_r2.0.1/src/com/android/camera/PhotoModule.java).
- The utility it uses to identify the ideal FPS starts on line 833 of com.android.camera.util.CameraUtil (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera2/+/android-4.4.4_r2.0.1/src/com/android/camera/util/CameraUtil.java)

Here's are the camera api calls to set the FPS **using hard coded values (for the sake of simplicity) specific to a Nexus 5.**

```
public void setFps(Camera camera) {
    Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
    params.setPreviewFpsRange(7000, 30000);
    camera.setParameters(params);
}
```

Comment: With the **relevant code** from the Android photo app I got what I needed, to get the appropriate values for FPS. Then I did the same but with those values instead of hardcoding them. Actually I am using the old Camera instead of Camera2 and the code for getting the FPS worked well.